# How do I create a basic JavaScript extension method which outputs the string 'Hello World'?

Tags: javascript

Not sure if the word 'extension method' is appropriate or not.  I want to extend the JavaScript language to allow me to call .helloWorld() on any object and it will always return the string 'Hello World'.

I have tried ...

```
Object.prototype.helloWorld = function () {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

... but this is causing problems with many other object types. I keep getting jQuery error...

```
Unhandled exception at line 3869, column 3 in http://workflow/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'splice'
```

Is it possible to extend the base class JavaScript object so that a custom method is available regardless of the type of object?  I have seen documentation on prototype but not sure if this is even the correct venue.  I have seen jQuery extend() but this seems jQuery specific.  I have seen discussions on extending methods vs. custom properties.  I am left confused.

Comment: Can you show an object that it has an error on? I can't reproduce.

Comment: @chrisz - the codebase I am playing with is large.  It could be my trivial example is not in the proper place in the JavaScript chain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is *possible*, and you can do it with just a [user script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript).

Extending the built-in JavaScript prototypes with non-standard properties and methods is generally considered a bad practice though, as it can often lead to unexpected behavior in code that didn't expect them.

If you do go there though, you can minimize the impact by making the property non-enumerable. That way code that iterates over an object's properties won't enumerate the property from the prototype chain.

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'helloWorld', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function () {
        return "Hello World";
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I am trying to learn how to extend existing objects and understand the plumbing.  I heed your advise - 'generally considered bad practice'.  This example you provided is using 'defineProperty'.  Is there a difference between a method and a property in JavaScript?

Comment: @barrypicker Not really. A method is just a property that is a function.

Comment: This works perfectly fine thank you.  I was hoping to see 'helloWorld' in the debugger when evaluating an object.  I don't see it in the list, but the function is working properly...  Is there something needed to make it show in the list of properties of the object in the debugger?

Comment: @barrypicker Depends on the browser's console. Probably making the property enumerable would accomplish that, but as mentioned that causes other problem. I don't think there is a way to do that without side effects. You could probably still find it by expanding the prototype chain though.

Answer (score 1):

Like said above use Object.defineProperty() method as the previous method Object.prototype._ *definegetter* _ has been deprecated in favor of the defineProperty method